# Node - Saving google openid to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am using nodejs with passport and so far I have successfully been able to allow a user to login to my app via google openID with the following:

```
passport.use( new GoogleStrategy({
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:22169/auth/google/return',
        realm: 'http://localhost:22169/'
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done) {
        // async verification
        process.nextTick( function() {
            profile.identifier = identifier;
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));
```

My next step once I got this working was to take the openID value ONLY and save it into a mongodb using mongoose. This is what I figured *should* work:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test'); 

var User = mongoose.model('User', { openId: String });

/*
  Some other stuff...
 */

passport.use( new GoogleStrategy({
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:22169/auth/google/return',
        realm: 'http://localhost:22169/'
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({ openId: identifier }, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    }
));
```

But when I run the node and try to login via google I get an error saying:

```
/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/b-server.js:42
        User.findOrCreate({ openId: identifier }, function(err, user) {
             ^
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'findOrCreate'
    at Strategy.app.configure.app.use.express.session.secret [as _verify] (/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/b-server.js:42:14)
    at /Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js:219:16
    at /Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1063:12
    at /Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1203:12
    at /Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1265:7
    at Object.openid.loadAssociation (/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:107:5)
    at _checkSignatureUsingAssociation (/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1231:10)
    at _checkSignature (/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1221:5)
    at _verifyAssertionAgainstProvider (/Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1184:3)
    at /Users/mporter/Sites/budgeter/node_modules/passport-google/node_modules/passport-openid/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1155:16
```

I assume it has to do something with the `User` keyword but I thought I did it correctly and created an appropriate mongoose model. Anyone care to lend a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport expects a `findOrCreate` method on your model as indicated above, but this method isn't built into mongoose models.  Try the [mongoose findorcreate plugin](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate), which will add the findOrCreate method to the models you specify.